# How to make signed kernel only runs at Secure Boot env.?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, ubuntu-22.04

I tried to play with secure boot at my Ubuntu PC (asus z370f ) based on the guide :
https://gloveboxes.github.io/Ubuntu-for-Azure-Developers/docs/signing-kernel-for-secure-boot.html

My concern is about the signed kernel which can run at non-secure boot enviroment without a MOK Key.
In fact , I am looking for a public avail. methodology  for Ubuntu OS at any intel CPU to achieve  the following goals :

1. user can seal a key into the CPU or NVRAM and the key or its hash is used to sign the kernel and initramfs
2. the signed kernel is tamper-proof and only run at secure  boot chain.

Is it still possible to make use of secure boot feature at intel CPU for Ubuntu 22.04 ?

For your info. , I tried to disable secure boot at my PC's UEFI firmware and the signed kernel still runs as usual.